# Reading from a file segmentation fault while running round robin algorithm

Tags: c, operating-system, round-robin

I get this error when trying to run round robin algorithm, and the algorithms are working perfectly fine when taking input from user. this is the code:

```
else if (select==2)
    {
        FILE * filehandle;
        char lyne[100];
        char *item;
        int reccount = 0;
        // open file
        filehandle = fopen("Input_Data1.txt","r");

        // Read file line by line
        while (fgets(lyne,99,filehandle))
        {
            numprocess =
            printf("%s",lyne);
            item = strtok(lyne," ");
            p[reccount].arrivetime =atoi(item);

            item = strtok(NULL," ");
            p[reccount].bursttime =atoi(item);

            reccount++;
        }
        //Close file
        fclose(filehandle);
    }
```

The error I get is segmentation fault (core dumped).

[screen shot of the input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcls4.png)

I tried reading from a file execting the same result as reading from user input but I got the error showed in the image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

**Avoid `atoi(NULL)`**

`item = strtok(lyne," ");` may return `NULL`.
`item = strtok(NULL," ");` may return `NULL`.

I suspect the 2nd should be `item = strtok(NULL," \n");`

**`NULL == filehandle`?**

Open may fail.

**`reccount` may exceed max**

**No need for a -1**

```
// fgets(lyne,99,filehandle)
fgets(lyne, sizeof lyne, filehandle)
```

---

```
    FILE * filehandle = fopen("Input_Data1.txt","r");
    if (filehandle == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Open failed\n"); 
      return;
    }
    char lyne[100];
    int reccount = 0;

    while (reccount < reccount_n && fgets(lyne, sizeof lyne, filehandle)) {
        numprocess = printf("%s", lyne); // Unclear how OP is using numprocess
        char *item = strtok(lyne," ");
        if (item == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "strtok(lyne,\" \") failed\n"); 
          return;
        }
        p[reccount].arrivetime =atoi(item);

        item = strtok(NULL," \n");
        if (item == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "strtok(NULL,\" \n\") failed\n"); 
          return;
        }
        p[reccount].bursttime =atoi(item);

        reccount++;
    }
    fclose(filehandle);
```

Comment: this solution didn't work

Comment: main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:173:48: error: stray ‘\’ in program
  173 |                 fprintf(stderr, "strtok(NULL," \n") failed\n");
      |                                                ^
main.c:173:47: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘n’
  173 |                 fprintf(stderr, "strtok(NULL," \n") failed\n");
      |                        ~                      ^ ~
      |                                               )

Comment: @SliumanAshraf Coding error in error messages corrected.

Comment: still recound_n is not declared

Comment: @SliumanAshraf `reccount_n` is something you need to supply.  It is the number of   elements in `p[]`.